Spotfire Counter for values in visualisation >0
I am building a Spotfire page which displays averages over a large dataset, but when pulling in a large amount of data there are some values which are 0. this is not the issue as the dataset is based on hours and targeted hours. when I create a calculated value for an average over the dataset within the visualization I can only get the count of entries, which throws the average off if there are only 2 values > 0 but there are 10 entries. ideally I would like a counter to count for the entries within the visual that are >0 so I can divide it by the SUM of the 2 positive entries within the dataset.
tried to use a counter to count for values >0 but getting error as ">" is not supported within Aggregation within Calculated Value

please show the expression you are using

currently using this within a calculated Value within a text box to display the average, - Sum([Hours] / UniqueCount([SerialNo]))
the Hours being hours Data, and SerialNo is the X axis on the visual. my problem is that if the Hours is 0 for an entry it will still count it within uniqueCount(SerialNo) as is it still within the visual. therefore when i calculate the average over the period it is no accurate as there is an extra entry with 0 hours

Try to surround your expression with a CASE WHEN END
something like:
MAX( CASE WHEN [Hours]>0 THEN Sum([Hours] / UniqueCount([SerialNo]) END )

Without the MAX(..) it will define your average only when [Hours] is greater than zero. So the call to MAX defines the column for all rows.
Note: It would be easier to read if you had updated your question rather than entering the expression in a comment.
